# Erasing raid metadata

Tags: 16.04, grub2, dmraid

I'm installing Ubuntu on my Dell XPS 15 9550, but I have problems with setting up grub. I get errors connected with efi partition access problems like:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/
```

My SSD disk is seen by gparted as /dev/nvme0n1, alread switched to AHCI in bios.
I'm thinking about erasing the raid metadata with:

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/nvme0n1
```

Is erasing this from the disk any risk? Should I backup anything?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a drive that used to be a RAID drive, and you want to use it as a regular drive, you can remove that information with the dmraid you suggest (I checked in the manual `man dmraid`). See also this link,

[Re: Ubuntu/Linux install problems with RAID](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1381608&p=8669890#post8669890)

So I am rather sure that it will work, but editing this kind of thing is always risky. Installing an operating system is also risky. So there are **strong reasons to backup all important data**.

It is a good habit to backup your important data regularly. You never know, when your drive will fail or be lost. It is easy to reinstall linux, but the family pictures?